# Cannot write IIS logs to Azure Files Share

Tags: logging, azure, iis-8.5, centralized-logging

I'd like to configure IIS (8.5) on an Azure VM to log to an Azure Files Share.

I've proved access to the share by remoting onto the VM and persisting credentials using cmdkey and then navigating successfully via the UNC path in Windows Explorer.

When I configure the IIS logging directory to point to the same UNC path I see this [unable to create log file error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hw6m.png) in the event log upon restarting IIS and browsing to a hosted site.

There doesn't seem to be a way to provide IIS with the credentials to use when it attempts to log to the Azure Files Share.  Whilst exploring options I used the PSExec tool to persist the share credentials for the system account but that did not resolve the issue.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I'm also looking to implement similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

IIS uses the local computers credentials (\ISSCOMPUTER$), not the users (or service principals) one. Just ad the (AD) account of the machine to your target.

Maybe it now comes to another common problem – where the web server is in another (or no) domain, and the UNC share is in somewhere else. You can still configure it by setting up the remote share as a Null Session share. You can set up a Null Session by following the steps in this [Technet article on how to create Null-Sessions](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a4939515-b651-4ee0-b327-867b31fd8c9a.mspx?mfr=true).